# Eclipse CVS: Can't CVS commit many (large) files

Tags: eclipse, configuration, cvs

I'm using CVS in Eclipse. I have a big set (approx. 600) of revised text files that I'd like to CVS commit.  Each file is about 1MB.  I found if I try to commit the whole parent directory or any large number of notebooks, say 50 of them, the commit never work.  I use highlight multiple files in Package Explorer -> context menu -> Team -> Commit to do that.  Right now, I just select a small number, say 10 of revised files and commit and it does work.  But it often takes multiple tries for it to work.  Is there any configuration or trick I can use?

I'm using Eclipse 4.3 with memory settings

```
...
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1536m
...
```

in eclipse.ini.

Storing the files in other places or VCS repository is not an option.  Using other CVS client or method for committing is OK.

Comment: "the commit never work" Do you get a partial commit (ie. just some of the files) or does the entire thing not work?

Comment: Entire thing does not work, AFAICT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, commiting files from eclipse list the files as the arguments of a classic cmd command "cvs commit file1 file2 ...". There is a limit on the number of the arguments in such a command. Therefore it can not handle larger number of files. The size can be a problem too.

I needed to commit about 30 000 files at once and the only way I was able to do this was writing a script and doing it recursively for every folder using "cvs commit -l" (invoked when folder was visited recursively).

I have tried tortoiseCVS but it crashed on the memory (needed around 1.3GB of RAM for this operation a it could not allocate it).